# Archive failed with custom framework

Tags: swift

I have the custom framework name LogginFramework and I use it in my project. I can debug and I can call the class of LogginFramework in my simulator. Now I tried to archive my project to send to the tester, build failed and showing" Use of unresolved identifier 'CryptoHelper'" How can I solve this issue? I already added framework in Embedded binaries and "Linked framework in Libraries" My Swift 3 app rebuilds and runs successfully on all simulators except for Generic iOS Device. If I try to archive it or do a rebuild on Generic iOS Device, I get a No such module error relating to my custom frameworks.
I tried build,clean,delete drived-data  but still error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you

1. Select your Project in Targets.
2. Then search for Skip install.
3. Change it into NO.
4. Then archive your custom framework. (make sure to use Generic
   iOS Device ) as a target device.
5. Export it to where you want.
6. Then use it with your project.